# grunt-karma not loading jasmine in phantom js

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, browserify, karma-jasmine

I have (roughly) the following directory setup

```
- project
  ...
  - tasks/
  - config/
      grunt.json
  - client/
      - source_code_1/
      - source_code_2/
      - tests/
  - Gruntfile.js
  - karma.config.json
  - node_modules
  - package.json
```

And are using browserify to bundle the JS.

This setup is real pain since all the grunt/karma/browserify code is totally mixed up with 
the server code.

What I want is to move everything into the client directory like

```
- project
  ...
  - client
    - tasks/
    - config
        - grunt.json
    - src/
       - source_code_1
       - source_code_2
    - tests
    - node_modules
    - Gruntfile.js
    - karma.config.json
    - package.json
```

This works perfectly with browserify as far as bundling the JS code and the dependencies for the tests.

The only problem is that karma is no longer able to find jasmine when it runs the tests.
I set the log level to DEBUG and it looks like the working setup runs:

```
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /project/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /project/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /project/node_modules/karma-commonjs/client/commonjs_bridge.js
```

after karma connects to the browser.

I'm not seeing these in the broken setup but the tasks and configs are the same. The only real difference is that node modules are in the client directory and the source code has moved into a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

The issue was with `karma-commonjs`. It's pretty greedy when it does its thing. The trick was to **not** include the `node_modules` directory during preprocessing.